# On finding the counterexample of a statement.

Tags: logic

The statement in question is : **For all** positive, odd integers $x$: $x$ is prime **or** $x$ is divisble by $k < x$.

I couldn't instantly come up with a counterexample, so I tried negating the statement, to see if that'd help.

The negation is: ***There exists*** a positive odd integer $x$: ***it's not the case*** that ($x$ is prime or $x$ is divisble by $ k<x$).

Which simplifies to:***There exists*** a positive odd integer $x$: $x$ is **not** a prime **and** $x$ is **not** divisble by $k < x$.

Is it possible that the statement has no counter example, or is my logic flawed.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your logic is perfect. How about $1$ ...

Comment: oh yeah, sure. I am such an idiot.

Comment: Don't feel bad ... you should see some of my brain farts! :)  And like I said, your logic was perfect: well done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider.  The definition of prime is  *not* divisible except by any positive factor except $x$ or $1$ and greater than $1$.  If $x$ is divisible by a factor $n$ and $n\ne x$ and $n \ne 1$ then $n < x$. (That's obvious isn't it?  If $x = nm$ then $n = \frac xm < \frac x1 = x$?)

So this is saying either: 1)  not divisible by any number less than itself and greater than 1 or 2) *is* divisible by a number less than itself.

"divisible by a number less than itself" and "not divisible by a number less than itself" are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, so the only possible counter example would be a number that is not divisible by itself and not greater than $1$.  The only positive integer that is not greater than $1$.... is $1$.

That's the single counter example.